# how to add id in mentio textarea div dynamically

Tags: angularjs

i want to use ment-io in my project from http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/#/examples.i had implement this about 100% .but that cannot be applicable in that. how to add id in mentio textarea div dynamically

my code :

```
<div contenteditable mentio
                        mentio-typed-term="typedTerm"
                        mentio-macros="macros"
                        mentio-require-leading-space="true"
                        class="editor form-control"
                        id="htmlContent{{index}}"
                        ng-model="htmlContent">
                    </div>
                    <mentio-menu
                            mentio-for="'htmlContent'"
                            mentio-trigger-char="'@'"
                            mentio-items="people"
                            mentio-search="searchPeople(term)"
                            mentio-select="getPeopleText(item)"
                            ></mentio-menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when using an `id` that has an expression in it, it will not have resolved by the time the `menito-menu` directive tries to locate the element. One way to work around this is to use a `ng-if` on `mentio-menu` that waits for the expression to have resolved.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BUjixoaGZ8f54ZTv84bh?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div contenteditable 
        mentio
        mentio-typed-term="typedTerm"
        mentio-require-leading-space="true"
        class="editor form-control"
        id="{{'htmlContent' + index}}"
        ng-model="htmlContent">
    </div>
    <mentio-menu ng-if="index"
        mentio-for="'htmlContent' + index"
        mentio-trigger-char="'@'"
        mentio-items="people"
        mentio-search="searchPeople(term)"
        mentio-select="getPeopleText(item)">
    </mentio-menu>
</body>
```

Or if you want to do it in an `ng-repeat` you could do something like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JslXZ4ETZa3qFZyPMbAK?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div contenteditable 
        mentio
        mentio-typed-term="typedTerm"
        mentio-require-leading-space="true"
        class="editor form-control"
        id="{{'htmlContent' + $index}}"
        ng-model="htmlContent">
    </div>
    <mentio-menu ng-if="item"
        mentio-for="'htmlContent' + $index"
        mentio-trigger-char="'@'"
        mentio-items="people"
        mentio-search="searchPeople(term)"
        mentio-select="getPeopleText(item)"
    ></mentio-menu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the element is the way to connect the mentio directive to its menu when it's specified externally.  If you only have one trigger char, one way you can work around this is just to move mentio-items, mentio-search and mentio-select on to the div.  If you have more than one trigger character, then you need the separate specification.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - A new version of ment-io was published: 0.9.12 that allows you to specify the ID of the mentio with the mentio-id field.  This attribute can contain {{'htmlContent' + index}} and will evaluate appropriately without the need for an ng-if.  See the ment.io project for details in the documentation.

http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/#/documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can directly edit the ID of the element via a directive on which you just add the id on the "elem" received as parameter (link stage).
Make sure mentio-menu triggers its init after your directive compilation (directive priority: ...).

Comment: i want to just use that variable Like {{index}} instead of static

Comment: an error is occure Error: triggerCharSet is undefined